# Saving user id from User table and facing error: Call to a member function save() on string

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried to store the userid  from user table in another car table as a foreign key.
User Table:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('userid')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Car table:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('plateno')->primary()->unique();
        $table->string('brand');
        $table->string('model');

        $table->string('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('userid')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

User Model and Car Model have 1 to 1 relationship.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
```

{
    use Notifiable;

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'userid', 'email', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function cars() 
{ 
    return $this->hasOne('App\Car', 'plateno' ); 
}
```

}

and here is the the store function for CarController

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'plateno' => 'required',
        'brand' => 'required',
        'model' => 'required'
    ]);

    $cars= new \App\Car;
    $cars->plateno=$request->get('plateno');
    $cars->brand=$request->get('brand');
    $cars->model=$request->get('model');

    $cars=Auth::user()->userid;
    $cars->save();
    return redirect('car')->with('success', 'User car has been added.');
}
```

thank you.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Call to a member function save() on string"

Stacktrace:
#0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError in C:\UnitenParking\app\Http\Controllers\CarController.php:59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an error:

```
$cars= new \App\Car;
$cars->plateno=$request->get('plateno');
$cars->brand=$request->get('brand');
$cars->model=$request->get('model');

$cars=Auth::user()->userid; // Here must be $cars->user_id = Auth::user()->userid;
$cars->save();
```

Replace `$cars=Auth::user()->userid;` with `$cars->user_id = Auth::user()->userId;`;

Comment: @WanAhmadImranIzzatWanZain When you specify your primary key and foreign key in migrations (table creation) it is not reasonable to refer your foreign key to something else later (here `id`). [See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Here `user_id` in `cars` table refers `userid` in `users` table, If you want to refer `user_id` in `cars` to `id` in `users` then you must change the foreign key definition in table creation (migration here) and absolutely your code must be changed like `$cars->user_id = Auth::id();`.